# Time difference between min and max timestamps in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to get the difference between minimal and maximal date-time rows
My naive attempt, which returns 0 was:

```
SELECT strftime( max(test_date)) - strftime( min(test_date))
FROM [t_score]
```

The date-time format is: `2015-54-07 13:11:56`

**UPDATE**

I have also tried the answer from lad2025, no success:
[image]

```
CREATE TABLE t_score(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
answered TEXT,
asked TEXT,
question TEXT,
session TIMESTAMP,
test_date TIMESTAMP,
test_id INTEGER,
user_id INTEGER)
```

**UPDATE 1**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can get difference between two dates in seconds using:

```
SELECT strftime('%s',max(test_date)) - strftime('%s',min(test_date)) AS diff_in_sec
FROM [t_score];
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/78888/6/0)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. I've tried this one but was getting an empty result. Pls. see the update.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz How do you store `test_date`? Show `t_score` table definition

Comment: OK, updated the question with the definition of t_score

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz Do you have any not NULL data in this column? Share result `SELECT test_date FROM t_score WHERE test_date IS NOT NULL`

Comment: OK, in UPDATE 1. There is some data there. This is strange indeed

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz Which version do you use? `SELECT sqlite_version()`